# where does Intellij install Scala compiler via the plugin

Tags: intellij-idea

I have installed `Scala` plugin in the `IntelliJ` compiler. I haven't installed it explicitly though on my laptop. Where does `IntelliJ` install `Scala` so that I can use the same compiler outside the `IntelliJ` IDE as well?

Answer (score 1):

IDE uses Scala from local Ivy cache: ".ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-compiler\jars"